# reset counter with thmtools

Tags: counters, thmtools

I am using `thmtools` to display theorems in a document. The theorems are numbered within a counter that is called 'entry' (this counter is defined within a command that is called 'entry' as well). So for the moment I use:

```
\declaretheorem[style=theorem,within=entry,name={}]{thm}
```

and an example of a displayed theorem is given by:

Theorem 2.3 -- Blabla

However, I want my theorems to be numbered just by one single number that is reset whenever I start a new entry in my document (by applying the entry command). So basically I want to get rid of the 2 in the numbering of the example above (which is referring to the entry counter).

Comment: in your preamble, add `\renewcommand{\thetheorem}{\arabic{theorem}}` *after* `\declaretheorem`.

Comment: remove the `within=entry` and say `\setcounter{thm}{0}` in your `\entry` command?

Comment: Perhaps a compilable document would also be very useful to provide more help!

Comment: The solution proposed by barbara beeton worked! Since it is not posted as answer I can't vote for it.

Answer (score 2):

any theorem that is "numbered within" will have a multi-part number.

if you wish to reduce this to a single-part number, with the value of the theorem
counter, in your preamble add the line

```
\renewcommand{\thetheorem}{\arabic{theorem}}
```

*after* `\declaretheorem`, when you are using `thmtools`; if you are using a
different theorem package, this same command can (usually) be used, again, *after* `\newtheorem` definitions or the equivalent.